Who supplies Israel with weapons?
Who supplies Israel with weapons? Is there any data (official, if it exists, and if not, estimates) about the proportion of Israel's weapons to have been sent by each country?

This information isn't exactly difficult to find, e.g., see Reuters. Israel also has domestic arms production.

Look at SIPRI https://www.sipri.org/databases/armstransfers  They carry exactly that type of info.

Please stop adding irrelevant tags to this question. Just because you think that the weapons Israel get supplied with might be used for "terrorism", "war crimes" or for the violation of "human rights" doesn't mean that this question itself is about any of these topics. If you keep doing this, then I will have to lock this question.

Seeing how the loaded selection of tags gets added again and again, The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician.

the tags are added by motivation.

Motivation is irrelevant for answering this question. Locked, then.

IDK how detailed you want this to be, but for the low-hanging fruit version, just in recent times, and by value, DW reports:

09/27/2024
Statistics gathered by the Stockholm International Peace Research Institute (SIPRI), and presented in a report published by the investigative group Forensic Architecture (FA) in April, show that in 2023, Germany was responsible for 47% of Israel's total imports of conventional arms, following the US at 53%.

Part of this of recent boost on Germany's account is due to navy vessels. Over time, that's been substantially more variable, i.e. in quite a few years over the past two decades the US approached or exceeded 90% of the share:

(Sorry for the minuscule fonts, it's like that in the source -- dark gray, bottom of the bars -- US, white portion on top of that -- Germany. Medium & very dark gray on top of those -- Italy and Canada.)
Also, over the years Israel has been constantly moving to more domestic production, but is more difficult to find sources for quantifying domestic vs imports share. [And technically, you didn't ask for that :D] As an example:

During 2014’s Operation Protective Edge, the Obama administration halted the delivery of Hellfire missiles for the Israeli Air Force’s Apache helicopters in order to pressure Netanyahu to end that conflict. The Air Force decided to adjust its Spike missiles to enable launching them from the Apache, in order to prevent dependency on future deliveries of the Hellfire missiles.

But more qualitatively speaking:

Even with the planned increased local military production, Israel would not manufacture warplanes, helicopters, warships, or submarines.

But "shells, precision weaponry, drones, tanks, jeeps, and various radar systems" are made locally already and they plan to increase the production and perhaps import fewer parts for those too.
As a side note, of what they do make, Israelis also export including to Germany, e.g. Germany "signed a deal to purchase the Arrow 3 long-range air defence system for around $4bn". So, it is a story of interdependence to some extent, with Germany at least. (Also, the Spike missile, which European buyers were unable to send to Ukraine, due to terms of use. That missile has become quasi-standard for European NATO countries nonetheless.) A somewhat useful graph in the latter regard, comparing imports with exports:



And if you prefer a 70- instead of a 20-year time frame, including destinations for both (albeit this stops in 2020, so it misses some recent deals):



